# Convert waveform image to audio file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm searching a way to covert a waveform image, to a simple wav file in javascript.
Do you know any library or framework in javascript that can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any plans yourself? Do you have an image we can see? Is it simple 8-bit midi or do you want full blown music?

Comment: The idea is to get an audio file, and produce the waveform, and then, have the possibility to get back to the audio file. I've already found a way to create the audii file, but I don't know how to get it back to the original audio